# Keypress event to click specific button

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, calculator

Is it possible to trigger click event on specific keyCode?
I mean ,for example in calculator. All buttons have onClick and depending on its name different functions are called.
If buttons name is 0-9 ,getNumber() is called. If buttons name is some kind of operator ,getOpereator() is called ,etc...

I've tried to Google it but all I could find was just firing click event on 'send' button while typing in  element. And that's i think whole different thing.

Then I've decided to try it like this

```
    document.addEventListener('keyup',function(e){
      if(e.which == 97){
        document.getElementsByName('1')[0].click();     
      }
    });
```

My idea was to add condition with specific keyCode for every keyboard button i would use (0-9 and +-*/. and enter for result)
I didn't think that's right solution for it ,but i gave that a shot and it doesn't work well.

When I press NUM1 for the first time everything's good, '1' appears in calculator display . But when I press it again ,result is not '11' as expected but '111'. After another hit result is not '111' but '1111111' and so on. There is some strange multiplication going on.

Funny thing about it is ,when I put it in codesandbox ,so I can share it with you here ,after press NUM1 just one time nine 1 pop up

**Link**

https://codesandbox.io/s/youthful-platform-n6lvs?fontsize=14&hidenavigation=1&theme=dark

Comment: are you appending pressed key to the existing number in the caclulator dispaly ?

Comment: Tried to open the sanbox, whenever I press 1 or any key, i got error.

Comment: I dont know why it throws error to you :O When I click on the link and press 1 on numpad ,there are no errors

Comment: Before pressing NUM1 ,try to click on rendered part of screen ,for example on calculator display. And then try to press NUM1